GMRES implementation does not converge for singular Hermitian problems
I've just implemented the GMRES algorithm based on chapter 4 of Fundamentals of Numerical Mathematics for Physicists and Engineers using the problems in Numerical Analysis by Timothy Sauer for validation. Implementation converges for all of the worked examples in the Prof Sauer's text but does not for the singular non-textbook problem.
#!/usr/bin/python3

import math
import copy
import numpy as np

TEXTBOOK_PROBLEM = True

if TEXTBOOK_PROBLEM:
    # From Numerical Analysis by Timothy Sauer
    # https://media.pearsoncmg.com/aw/aw_sauer_num_analysis_3/solutions/sol_4_4.html
    A = np.array([
                    [ 1, 1, 0],
                    [-1, 1, 2],
                    [ 0, 0, 1]
                    ])

    b = np.array(
        [[1],
         [0],
         [0]])
else:
    A = np.array(
    [[  53,   83,  101,  119,  133,  161,    0,    0,    0],
     [  83,  130,  158,  187,  209,  253,    0,    0,    0],
     [ 101,  158,  194,  221,  247,  299,    0,    0,    0],
     [ 119,  187,  221, 1130, 1222, 1464, 1189, 1247, 1363],
     [ 133,  209,  247, 1222, 1322, 1584, 1271, 1333, 1457],
     [ 161,  253,  299, 1464, 1584, 1898, 1517, 1591, 1739],
     [   0,    0,    0, 1189, 1271, 1517, 1681, 1763, 1927],
     [   0,    0,    0, 1247, 1333, 1591, 1763, 1849, 2021],
     [   0,    0,    0, 1363, 1457, 1739, 1927, 2021, 2209]])

    b = np.array(
    [[  650],
     [ 1020],
     [ 1220],
     [ 8142],
     [ 8778],
     [10506],
     [ 9348],
     [ 9804],
     [10716]])

################################################################################
# Uses Given's rotation to convert an upper Hessenberg matrix H to an upper
# triangular matrix which is trivial to solve.
def solve(H):
    numRows, numCols = H.shape
    b = np.hstack(([1], np.zeros(numRows - 1)))
    x = np.zeros(numCols)

    # Given's rotation (converts upper Hessenberg matrix to upper triangular matrix)
    for i in range(numCols):
        d = math.sqrt(H[i][i]**2 + H[i + 1][i]**2)
        s = H[i + 1][i]/d
        c = H[i][i]/d
        e1 = b[i]
        e2 = b[i + 1]
        b[i] = c*e1 + s*e2
        b[i + 1] = c*e2 - s*e1
        for j in range(i, numCols):
            r1 = H[i][j]
            r2 = H[i + 1][j]
            H[i][j]     = c*r1 + s*r2
            H[i + 1][j] = c*r2 - s*r1

    # Solve upper triangular matrix
    for i in range(numCols - 1, -1, -1):
        accum = 0
        for j in range(numCols - 1, i, -1):
            accum = x[j]*H[i][j]
        x[i] = (b[i] - accum)/H[i][i]

    return x

################################################################################

index = 1
terminate = False

q = b/np.linalg.norm(b)
h = np.array([[0.0]])

while True:
    h = np.vstack((h, [0]*h.shape[-1])) # adds a row of zeros
    Aq = A.dot(q[:,-1])
    Q = copy.deepcopy(Aq)

    for i in range(index):
        value = q[:,-index + i]
        h[i][-1] = np.dot(value, Aq)
        Q -= h[i][-1]*value

    h[index][-1] = np.linalg.norm(Q)
    c = solve(copy.deepcopy(h))

    if h[index][-1] == 0:
        x = q.dot(c) # solution
        print(x)
        break
    else:
        q = np.column_stack((q, Q/h[index][-1]))

    h = np.column_stack((h, np.zeros(len(h))))
    index += 1

The singular (non-textbook) problem is solvable by numpy as follows:
from scipy.sparse.linalg import gmres
x, exitCode = gmres(A, b, atol=1e-5)
print(exitCode)


Can you check if things dramatically improve if you add at least the diagonal preconditioning? (see this answer of mine on a different question for some context).

Is the non-textbook problem singular? GMRES is guaranteed to converge in at most $n$ iterations if a solution exists. ($n$ is the size of the matrix). It may be that the scipy implementation has some heuristics in place for singular problems that are not present in the textbook algorithm.

@whpowell96 The problem I am trying to solve is singular. Do you know any strategies for solving singular problems.

I recommend you update your post to reflect the fact that the matrix is singular. I will write a short answer

@AntonMenshov The diagonal preconditioner does not help.

A singular problem either has no, or infinitely many solutions. What exactly do you expect to happen when you say "it does not converge"?

MINRES-QLP appears to be the few algorithms capable of solving singular symmetric and Hermitian Linear systems.

I believe conjugate gradients also can do so as long as the system is consistent. MINRES and the conjugate residual (CR) method on the other hand work also when the system is inconsistent.

MINRES has been extended to singular matrices (it minimizes A*residual instead of the residual): https://www.gerad.ca/en/papers/G-2023-40

@lightxbulb I agree on CG; an explanation of why it works on PSD matrices is in my answer here.

@FedericoPoloni I have read and upvoted your answer before. For the statement about MINRES see web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/software/minres It will give you the least square solution but not necessarily the minimum length one. For the CR case just note that it is essentially CG but with an inner product using $A$. Albeit CG will not work for indefinite symmetric systems, while CR, MINRES should work afaik. (I updated my comment because I had written that it will not give you the least squares solution, while I meant to write that it will not give you the minimum length solution.)
